# Nvidia Proprietary Drivers Not Populating in Fresh 18.04 Installation

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, gpu-driver

PC Build:

- X11SAT-F Supermicro Mobo
- Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070/PCIe/SSE2
- Intel® Core™ i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz × 8
- Ubuntu 18.04 x 64

I tried:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt update
```

Rebooted my PC and ran the software update GUI and got the options
[Available Graphics drivers, no Proprietary drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFL9B.png)

**418** is the proper driver version for my card according to the Nvidia website.

Several forums have posts on similar issues but after purging and reconstructing the repository, they seem to get a proprietary option. I have purged and updated the repository several times but still just get the "Open Source" driver options which don't have the Nvidia control panel.

Does anyone know how I can get force the repository to get the official Nvidia drivers.